# backfilling a DB with async await inside of a while loop JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function triggered `onClick` from my client which is supposed to back fill a separate DB with the first 100 items from the api.

**seedDb()**

```
  async function seedDb() {
    let i = 0;
    let offset = 0;

    while (i <= 100) {
      console.log(i);

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://someapi?limit=20&offset=${offset}`
      );

      await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/marvel", data);

      offset = i;
      i += 20;
    }
  }
```

this is the functionality of the `/marvel` endpoint

```
export const backFill = async (req, res) => {
  const { data } = req.body;
  formatAndSaveData(data.results)

}

const formatAndSaveData = async (array) => {
  const marvelChars = array.map((res) => {
    return {
      name: res.name,
      description: res.description,
      marvelId: res.id
    }
  })

  await prisma.Character.createMany({
    data: marvelChars
  })
  console.log('Success')
}
```

The problem I'm having is the `axios.post` req is stopping the loop from executing again. In the logs I see `i` logs once as `0` Is there any work around for this?

Comment: How are you invoking seedDb?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule its trigged onClick

Comment: a) `backFill` never writes a http response to the client, so the axios call will stay pending b) it should be either `const data = req.body;`, `const data = await axios.get(…)` or `axios.post("http://localhost:3001/marvel", { data });`